# Custom Page Border

Tags: border, page

How can i create a page template that looks like this:
[image]

Where the default paper is A4 and I want my ctext to be located in the big rectangle?
The distances represent how far away it should be from the borders of the A4 paper.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Should 25 and 35 mm be the left and right margins? And the page number should be in the right margin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a border around your text, I would suggest you leave some space between the border and the text. For your page template, you could use a combination of the `geometry` package, the `fancyhdr` package and some TikZ for the frames:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
    top=8mm,
    bottom=8mm,
    left=27mm,
    right=44mm,
    marginparwidth=31mm,
    marginparsep=4mm
    ]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture] {
    \draw ([shift={(25mm,-7mm)}]current page.north west) rectangle ++(178mm,-283mm);
    \draw ([shift={(168mm,-7mm)}]current page.north west) -- ++(0,-283mm);
    \draw ([shift={(168mm,-13mm)}]current page.north west) -- ++(35mm,0);
    \node[minimum width=31mm] at ([shift={(185.5mm,-10mm)}]current page.north west) {Page \thepage};
} }

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]\marginpar{This is an annotation in the margin.}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]